# Set conditions at a permutation

Tags: permutation, conditional

I need to find all permutations of 3 elements from `{a,b,c,d,e}` with this condition: These must include element `d` maximum once, and a must be before `c`. I'm using the following code and I don't know how to set the condition. Anyone help :)

```
Permutations[list, {3}];
perm[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_] := Module[{perm},
   list = {a, b, c, d, e};
    k = Tuples[list, 3];
     perm];
```

Comment: Are you sure you did your homework? A [Permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) is per definition a *rearrangement* of members from a set. When your set `{a,b,c,d,e}` contains only one `d`, then there is no way it can ever have more than one `d` in all existing permutations. Can you clear what exactly you mean?

Answer (score 3):

I interpret your query differently from *kguler* - I believe you're after this:

```
result = Select[Tuples[{a, b, c, d, e}, 3], 
   Count[#, d] <= 1 && ! MatchQ[#, {___, c, ___, a, ___}] &];

result // Short
```

[image]