# how to permute list of number{1,2,3,...,n},while preserve the order of first m terms as well as the last n-m terms?

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

For example, starting from `{1,2,3,4}`, I want to generate all permutations like `{1,3,2,4},{1,3,4,2},{3,4,1,2}` which preserve the order of e.g first two terms `{1,2}` and the order of e.g. last two terms `{3,4}`

I've tried to use the `Permutation` function, but it cannot preserve the order of `{1,2}` and `{3,4}`.

Comment: Do you mean something like `Tuples[{1, 2, 3}, 3]` or `Permutations[{1, 2, 3}]`?

Comment: Please include the "last n-m terms" in the body of your question; it should not be necessary to read the title to answer the question.

Comment: Sorry. For example, I want to permute {1,2,3,4,5},while preserving the order of first 3 terms(i.e.{1,2,3}) and the order of last 2 terms(i.e.{4,5}). For instance, {1,4,2,5,3} and {4,1,2,5,3} satisfies my requirement, because the order of {1,2,3} and the order of {4,5} are not changed.

Comment: Somewhat related: [(82522)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82522/121)

Comment: Is speed important and are larger cases needed? If so, answers so far can be handily beaten...

Comment: @ciao You sure do like to dangle the carrot, don't you? :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - not at all - it's simply a case of prompting to see if the effort to code up an idea is warranted - I see problem, play code in head, guesstimate performance benefit, usually close... in this case, I was thinking of the extended interpretation (which can be done more quickly than what's here), but realized after re-reading question the OP is after simple shuffle-product as noted elsewhere. If OP says they need other interpretation *and* speed matters, I'll happily code up idea.

Comment: @ciao As you can see I have closed this as a duplicate.  Since you have a method in mind that will beat `oP2` would you be willing to post a self-Q&A to share it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - sure, I'll take the time to code it up and compare, if correct in performance estimate, I'll post - but that's 2 things I have in the queue at your request (the other is the matrix generators - I hope you didn't think I meant they're in one handy place when I used the word "library" - I meant it in the sense of a collection, which in my case is as organized as a lazy teenager's bedroom), so don't hold your breath, and sorry ahead of time for my guaranteed tardiness...

Comment: @ciao I am the reigning king of procrastination and tardiness around here; you've got a long way to go to dethrone me. ;o)  I fully understand if the library thing never happens as I've got half-finished answers scattered all across this site with things like "I'll continue this tomorrow" at the bottom.  It's really quite embarrassing but nobody has particularly called me out on it so I hope I don't annoy too many with it.

Comment: I cannot seem to post this as an answer: `Pick[#, OrderedQ /@ (# /. (1 | 2 | 3) -> Nothing)] &@
   Pick[#, OrderedQ /@ (# /. (4 | 5 | 6 | 7) -> Nothing)] &@
 Permutations[Range[7]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. [1-2] I'm not sure that I agree that this question is a duplicate, or that any of the answers you link to add anything other than one particular interpretation of the OP question. In general terms, the OP may want to generate permutations while preserving the order of certain terms. For example, to preserve the order of the first and last terms, and to preserve the order of all 'middle' terms: `Pick[#, OrderedQ /@ (# /. (1 | 7) -> Nothing)] &@ Pick[#, OrderedQ /@ (# /. (2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6) -> Nothing)] &@ Permutations[Range[7]]`.

Comment: [2-2] Or, to preserve the order of the first and last terms only: `Pick[#, OrderedQ /@ (# /. (2 | 3 | 4) -> Nothing)] &@
 Permutations[Range[5]]`

Comment: @TomD If we assume than the "n" in "{1,2,3,...,n}" and "n-m terms" is the same, then this question became the duplicate as it is presently marked.  (Or so I believe.)  I guess we must await clarification from user41614.  Kuba's code and my adaptation of it does allow preservation of order of arbitrary non-intersecting disjoint selections from the input list, without the inefficiency of total enumeration followed by filtering.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard.  I accept that your code is more efficient. But is seems to me it is also quite complex and 'non-obvious' for a relatively simple task?  I do not like the way you closed this question only after a number of users (including yourself) had posted informative answers, and where now no-one else can contribute.  It is such behaviour that has made me (and others) become very disillusioned with SO.  It used to be that  anyone could ask a question, and that anyone could answer a question.

Comment: @TomD If you read the comments above you will see that I was hoping for a *new* question to separate the two interpretations of this post.  It was never my intent to limit answers, but instead to give them the best platform possible.  I certainly do not wish to contribute to your disillusionment and I hope that I am *always* responsive to such concerns.  I shall reopen this question right now.  Since you area also taking the more interesting interpretation it would probably be best to edit the question to explicitly match or at least include that.

Comment: @TomD Separately I am troubled by your comment "It is such behaviour that has made me (and others) become very disillusioned with SO."  I would like to learn of your concerns and address them as I am able.  Would you please consider opening a [Meta] question on the topic?

Comment: @ciao Please note the development above.  I am doing my best to please everyone and hopefully not making a hash of it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - hey, keep me out of the cat herding. ..

Comment: @user106 I have been hoping to hear from you and I see that you have not posted on Meta.  I am genuinely concerned about your disillusionment and I am still hoping you will let me do my best to address it if you will engage me in a dialog.

Answer (score 9):

```
pos = {{1, 2}, {4, 5}};
list = {a, b, c, d, e};
```

This answer is more general, OP wants to split the list on two parts while I'm allowing not covered elements to be permuted freely, thus unnecessarily complicated.

- we replace elements in the same group with the same unique symbol e.g `{x, x, c, y, y}`
- we take advantage of the fact that `Permutations` considers repeated elements identical,
- we replace unique symbol ocurrences with consecutive elements from old groups

Ugly implementation

```
Module[{
  temp = list,      
  uni = Unique[] & /@ pos,      
  elements = list[[#]] & /@ pos,
  i
  },

 MapThread[(temp[[#]] = #2 ) &, {pos, uni}];

 Fold[
   (i = 1; # /. #2[[1]] :> #2[[2, i++]]) &,
   #, 
   Transpose[{uni, elements}]
 ] & /@ Permutations[temp]  


 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's ugly.

Comment: This method seems familiar.  I have a suspicion that this question has been asked before.  Nevertheless +1 for some nice coding!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, and I think so. p.s. I overdid it since I allowed to specify parts which don't contain whole list, while OP only needs to split the list on two parts. As Coolwater shows.

Comment: Generality is always nice however!

Comment: This may have been the problem I was remembering and it is certainly not a duplicate: [(32404)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32404/121)

Comment: I think I either misunderstand your intent or something is wrong here.  If I convert your shorter code to a function `oP` and then run `oP[{"w", "i", "z", "a"}, {{1, 2, 4}}]` I get `{{"w", "i", "a", "z"}, {"w", "i", "z", "a"}, {"w", "a", "i", "z"}, {"a", "w", "i", "z"}}` -- I was expecting "w", "i", and "a" to remain in that order, but instead I get things like `{"a", "w", "i", "z"}`.  Comment?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - as stated in the OP, this is just the shuffle-product, asked and answered before...

Comment: @ciao I now see the close relation to [(41614)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41614/121) (thanks!) but unless I am missing something this is not "just" the shuffle-product as a subset of the elements (those not specified as ordered) may appear in any order.  Doesn't that complicate this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard- since the first N are carved out, and then the remaining are carved out, it's *exactly* a shuffle-product. If OP said "first x and last y" where y is not length-x, it's a bit different (or for that matter using arbitrary groups), it's still just a shuffle-product with non-group members permuted...

Comment: @ciao Dare to create a generic topic about that?, I too recognize it is relatively common topic yet usually I don't know what to look for.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard since your answer is a fixed version of my naive approach I will just leave here the old one.

Answer (score 9):

I think one should avoid `Permutations`, because it imposes unnecessarily high complexity. E.g:

```
go[L_, m_] := Normal[SparseArray[Flatten[With[{R = Range[Length[L]]},
 MapIndexed[Thread[Thread[{First[#2],
  Join[#, Complement[R, #]]}] -> L] &, Subsets[R, {m}]]], 1]]]

go[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2]
```

Comment: @Kuba I put the first `m` elements at whichever ordered positions are possible (from `Subset`). I put the rest `n-m` elements (in order because of `Complement`) on remaining positions, so i wouldn't expect that.

Comment: @Kuba The title contradicts that interpretation, even though the special case in the question text coincide with it

Comment: You are right, I have misinterpreted the question

Answer (score 6):

Working with Kuba's redacted method (which had problems) I came up with this:

```
oP2[list_, groups_] :=
  Module[{idx, ele},
    idx = ArrayComponents[
      Range @ Length @ list, 1,
      MapIndexed[Alternatives @@ # -> #2[[1]] &, groups]
    ];
    ele = list[[Ordering @ idx]];
    ele[[#]] & /@ Ordering /@ Ordering /@ Permutations @ idx
  ]
```

It appears to work correctly:

```
oP2[{"w", "i", "z", "a", "r", "d"}, {{3, 6}, {1, 2, 4}}] // Shallow
```

> ```
> {{w,i,z,a,r,d},{w,i,z,a,d,r},{w,i,z,r,a,d},{w,i,z,r,d,a},{w,i,z,d,a,r},
>  {w,i,z,d,r,a},{w,i,a,z,r,d},{w,i,a,z,d,r},{w,i,a,r,z,d},{w,i,r,z,a,d},<<50>>}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Several interpretations that seem to do other than what the OP is asking for resulting in unnecessary code complexity..

This is simply a shuffle-product as stated in OP (the first N of length M shuffled with the remaining M-N of the list.)

This uses some code for the SP I did long ago, with a `TakeDrop` tacked on to provide specification of `N` per OP. Quite good performance, and if OP needs functionality of other interpretations (e.g., first N and last N of list with rest fully permuted, etc.), easily adapted to such cases.

```
op = With[{j = Join @@ {##}, sp = Permutations[Join @@ ConstantArray @@@Transpose[{Range@Length@{##}, Length /@ {##}}]]},
      Partition[j[[Flatten[Ordering[Ordering[#]] & /@ sp]]], Length[j]]] & @@ TakeDrop@## &;
```

Use, (e.g. list of length 7 with first 3 and last 4 properly ordered):

```
op[{1,2,3,4,5,6,7},3]
```

Comment: Ah, now I finally see the interpretation you were referring to.  I somehow was blind to "n" being the same value.  However by this interpretation the question is a duplicate of [(41614)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41614/121) and should be closed as such.  Should we edit it to instead be the generalization that Kuba addressed, or close it and post a new question with that description?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Is that "we" a nosism?    ;=}

As the OP is written, I'd consider it a duplicate, but the generalization *is* interesting, so.... your call, I had no plan to close-vote as dupe.

Comment: By "we" I expressly meant *you* and *me*.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I know - it was a joke, hope not taken the wrong way. Court jester fail...

Comment: I did not take it the wrong way, you made your mood clear with an emoji; I however did not, so "fail" on my end.  Seriously, little bits of humor from you, belisarius, Daniel, Simon, and others really add to the experience here; please don't stop.

Comment: Interpreting the question as you have done, and using the 'brute force' approach: `Pick[#, OrderedQ /@ (# /. (1 | 2 | 3) -> Nothing)] &@
    Pick[#, OrderedQ /@ (# /. (4 | 5 | 6 | 7) -> Nothing)] &@
  Permutations[Range[7]] == op[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 3]`

Answer (score 3):

```
n = 5; m = 3;
a = Range[n];
left = Subsets[a, {m}];
right = Complement[a, #] & /@ left;
perm = MapThread[Join, {left, right}]
Permute[a, #] & /@ perm//TableForm
```

Explanation: 
We prepare first a list of all possible permutations using `Subsets` and `Complement`. Subsequently we `Join` permutations for the left $m$ and right $n-m$ objects and apply permutations by using `Permute`. As a result we obtain:

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} & 4 & 5 \\
 \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & 4 & \mathbf{3} & 5 \\
 \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & 4 & 5 & \mathbf{3} \\
 \mathbf{1} & 4 & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{2} & 5 \\
 \mathbf{1} & 4 & \mathbf{2} & 5 & \mathbf{3} \\
 \mathbf{1} & 4 & 5 & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} \\
 4 & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} & 5 \\
 4 & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & 5 & \mathbf{3} \\
 4 & \mathbf{1} & 5 & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} \\
 4 & 5 & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Notice, this example is slightly different from the one in OP. Here $n=5$, $m=3$.

Comment: This seems to miss some cases, e.g. 2 is never the last element.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Please, notice that in my example `m=3`and therefore 2 cannot be the last element.

Comment: noted! I was expecting the same output provided by OP. I should have read more closely. I can't change my vote w/o an edit now :( If you edit to point out that you've given a different case from OP's example I'll upvote it.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Now a note is added and additionally an illustration is provided

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Fold` to apply patterns repeatedly to cull the list of permutations:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4};
patterns = {___, #1, ___, #2, ___} & @@@ Partition[list, 2];
```

This generates the patterns `{{___, 1, ___, 2, ___}, {___, 3, ___, 4, ___}}` which can be applied using Fold:

```
Fold[
 Cases[#1, #2] &,
 Permutations[list],
 patterns
 ]
```

The meat of the answer is the application of Fold and Cases to a list of patterns that you want to apply. The first application selects all cases where 1,2 are ordered, and the second takes only the cases of that subset in which 3,4 are ordered.