# Duties of Threads accompanied by `#` or a Rule `->`

Tags: list-manipulation

I was willing to understand the Coolwater's solution of the presented problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120690/how-to-permute-list-of-number1-2-3-n-while-preserve-the-order-of-first-m-t?newsletter=1&nlcode=522017%7Cc3e8). He proposed the below solution

```
 go[L_, m_] := Normal[SparseArray[Flatten[With[{R = Range[Length[L]]},
 MapIndexed[Thread[Thread[{First[#2],
 Join[#, Complement[R, #]]}] -> L] &, Subsets[R, {m}]]], 1]]]

 go[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2]
```

In a reverse procedure I have obtained

```
 L = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; R = Range[Length[L]]; m = 2;
 Subsets[R, {m}]
(**{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}}**)

MapIndexed[
Thread[Thread[{First[#2], Join[#, Complement[R, #]]}] -> L] &, 
Subsets[R, {m}]]

(**{{{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> 2, {1, 3} -> 3, {1, 4} -> 4, {1, 5} -> 
 5}, {{2, 1} -> 1, {2, 3} -> 2, {2, 2} -> 3, {2, 4} -> 4, {2, 5} -> 
 5}, {{3, 1} -> 1, {3, 4} -> 2, {3, 2} -> 3, {3, 3} -> 4, {3, 5} -> 
 5}, {{4, 1} -> 1, {4, 5} -> 2, {4, 2} -> 3, {4, 3} -> 4, {4, 4} -> 
 5}, {{5, 2} -> 1, {5, 3} -> 2, {5, 1} -> 3, {5, 4} -> 4, {5, 5} -> 
 5}, {{6, 2} -> 1, {6, 4} -> 2, {6, 1} -> 3, {6, 3} -> 4, {6, 5} -> 
 5}, {{7, 2} -> 1, {7, 5} -> 2, {7, 1} -> 3, {7, 3} -> 4, {7, 4} -> 
 5}, {{8, 3} -> 1, {8, 4} -> 2, {8, 1} -> 3, {8, 2} -> 4, {8, 5} -> 
 5}, {{9, 3} -> 1, {9, 5} -> 2, {9, 1} -> 3, {9, 2} -> 4, {9, 4} -> 
 5}, {{10, 4} -> 1, {10, 5} -> 2, {10, 1} -> 3, {10, 2} -> 
 4, {10, 3} -> 5}}**)
```

Which are some results of the solution parties. But I have tried to understand what happen in  the first Thread `Thread[{First[#2], Join[#, Complement[R, #]]}]` and the second Thread `Thread[Thread[{First[#2], Join[#, Complement[R, #]]}] -> L]`.

Because in the first Thread have used `#` which returns to `Subsets[R, {m}]` and inside the second Thread have used `->`. I cannot use of just `Subsets[R, {m}]` for investigating the Thread process also in the Mathematica help I cannot find a Thread with `->`.

In fact what is the duties of two used Thread?!! Can anyone say in a clarified way?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact this is more likely a extended comment which may gives you some idea of how these two `Thread` work.

To begin with, let's use `Echo` to conveniently get what's the input is:

```
go[L_, m_] := 
 Normal[SparseArray[
   Flatten[With[{R = Range[Length[L]]}, 
     MapIndexed[
      Thread[Thread[Echo@{First[#2], Join[#, Complement[R, #]]}] -> 
         Echo@L] &, Subsets[R, {m}]]], 1]]]
```

Let's take one out and check what's happening:

```
{1,{1,2,3,4,5}}
{1,2,3,4,5}
```

The first level of `Thread` is used in this form: `Thread[{1,{1,2,3,4,5}}]` which means the same as `Thread[{{1,1,1,1,1},{1,2,3,4,5}}]` and generate a result of `{{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5}}`.

Then at the second level, it's the normal form of Thread working. Note that `Thread` may work on any `Head` and `list1->list2` is actually `Rule[list1,list2]`, thus Thread can work on this and change it into a list of rules. Thus `Thread[{{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5}}->{1,2,3,4,5}]` will return `{{1,1}->1,{1,2}->2,{1,3}->3,{1,4}->4,{1,5}->5}`.

Will this explanation help? Is this what you need?

Comment: Your comment, and explanation is very useful. `Echo` which I don't know before is the keyword which clarifies the procedure.